# How to submit a contact form in wordpress using phpmailer and where to redirect it

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

where to put this configuration code

```
session_start();

require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

require 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';
$result="";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$to = "username"; 
$from = "username"; 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$company = $_POST['company'];

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];

$msg = 'Full Name : '. $name . " " .  "\n\n<br>" . 'Corporate Email : ' . $_POST['email']."\n\n<br>" 
. 'Mobile : ' . $_POST['mobile']."\n\n<br>" . 'Company : ' . $_POST['company']   . "\n\n<br>" . 
'Subject 
: ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n\n<br>" . 'Message : ' . $_POST['msg'];


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);          // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                     // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                             // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.rediffmailpro.com';   // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;           // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'username';          // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'pass';                          // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';            // Enable TLS encryption`ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                           // TCP port to connect to

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress('username', 'Seema User');     // Add a recipient
          // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('username', 'Seema');

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = $_post['subject'];
$mail->Body    = $msg;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send())
{
$result="Something went wrong......";
}
else{
    $result="Your inquiry has been submitted, our team will get in touch with you shortly.";
}


} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Normally we include it in that same file or can make another file to control it but wordpress has it's own rules to control it. Can anyone explain how to use phpmailer code in wordpress step by step.
I would be greatful to you if you will help me.

Comment: Have you created a custom form for the inquiry or are you using any plugin?

Comment: i am using a custom form.          https://act21softwares.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/incentivo-aniket-theme/contact.php

Comment: Are you going to use the form this way? This is a form of CORE PHP, and you are calling PHP file directly into WP. You can show this form using the page template so permalink structure will be followed. Secondly, you can debug it for included files. I don't think it includes files with proper paths.